# MySQL round(x,1) returns 0.0 and -0.0

Tags: mysql, rounding

Tell me if the two zeros make sense:

```
select x, count(1) from (select round(rand()-0.5,1) x from tab) t group by x;
+------+----------+
| x    | count(1) |
+------+----------+
| -0.5 |     1830 |
| -0.4 |     3726 |
| -0.3 |     3753 |
| -0.2 |     3835 |
| -0.1 |     3828 |
|  0.0 |     1909 |
| -0.0 |     1889 |
|  0.1 |     3831 |
|  0.2 |     3753 |
|  0.3 |     3793 |
|  0.4 |     3690 |
|  0.5 |     1887 |
+------+----------+
```

There is a workaround (cast as decimal(10,1)) but I am curious if round() is broken. I am using MySQL 5.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IEEE floating point standard has two zeros: positive and negative. It's totally normal for round() to return a negative zero when rounding a negative value up to 0.

Normally the negative zero is treated equal to positive zero, but it looks like on your platform MySQL considers them distinct.

**Update:** MySQL, at least in 5.5, seems to consider positive and negative zero equal for `=`, but distinct for `GROUP BY`.

You can add zero to a value to convert a negative zero to positive with no changes for other values. For example,

```
select x, count(1) from (select 0+round(rand()-0.5,1) x from tab) t group by x;
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think this is a MySQL bug that should be fixed?

Comment: It's hard to say, certainly it's surprising that sometimes the two zeros are equal and sometimes not. You can try submitting a bug report and see what they say.